# Roboguice - Android - How much memory consumed by Roboguice

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, roboguice, memory-consumption

How do we come to know that how much memory Roboguice is using. E.g. When app starts how much memeory used by RoboguiceContext, after cerrtain actions whats the updated memory position etc.

We have all the field injections, so wanted to know about life of these injected objects as well like how long these objects will be available and how much memory is consumed by these injected objects.

Please share some way or code snippet to achieve this, the requirement of these figures is because of our app consumes lot memory and don't want to leave a single chance to reduce memory consumption. Here, Roboguice is the context so we need to understand memory model for this first.

Thanks a lot in advace!